# NextJS - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type - but I don't think that's what is actually going on

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, next.js, expo

So I've got this error, but I don't actually think that's the problem, as I have a very similar setup, in another app. This is in a React Native Web/Expo/NextJS app based on this:

```
 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (21:4)
 You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See 
 https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
 | const GeneralStatusBarColor = ({ backgroundColor, height,     ...props }) => {
 |   return (
 >     <SafeAreaView style={{ height: height, backgroundColor: backgroundColor }}>
 |       <StatusBar
 |         {...props}
```

But, I have a .babelrc file, based off this repo, and some of my own changes:

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/nativebase-templates/tree/master/solito-universal-app-template-nativebase-typescript

```
{                        
  "presets": [                        
    "next/babel",                        
    ["babel-preset-expo", { "jsxRuntime": "automatic" }]                        
  ],                        
  "plugins": [                        
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],                        
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }],                        
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }],                        
    "react-native-reanimated/plugin",                        
    [                        
      "module-resolver",                        
      {                        
        "root": "../../packages",                        
        "alias": {                        
          "app": "../../packages/app",                        
          "components": "../../packages/app/components",                        
          "config": "../../packages/app/config",                        
          "controllers": "../../packages/app/controllers",                        
          "pages": "../../packages/app/pages",                        
          "features": "../../packages/app/features",                        
          "reducers": "../../packages/app/redux",                        
          "resources": "../../packages/app/resources",                        
          "revenuecat": "../../packages/app/revenuecat",                        
          "routing": "../../packages/app/routing",                        
          "utils": "../../packages/app/utils",                        
          "interfaces": "../../packages/app/interfaces",                        
          "root": "./"                        
        }                        
      }                        
    ]                        
  ]                        
}
```

I also have a webpack definition in my next.config.js:

```
webpack: (config, options) => {
      config.resolve.alias = {
        ...(config.resolve.alias || {}),
        'react-native$': 'react-native-web',
        '@expo/vector-icons': 'react-native-vector-icons',
      };
      config.resolve.extensions = [
        '.web.js',
        '.web.ts',
        '.web.tsx',
        ...config.resolve.extensions,
      ];
      return config;
    }
```

Now I can get rid of this error by adding more webpack code inside my next.config.js, but I have another app where I don't need this, and it works fine, and when I DO put loader code inside my webpack settings in next.config.js, it causes a whole lot of other issues.

So what exactly is going on here? Where could this loader problem be originating from?